# learning sed, having trouble extracting text between to values

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file with text in it that looks like this:

```
ssid="sdfsdf" #psk="sdfsfsdf" psk=zzzs93j03r093ur0fjfs39uj }
```

I'm learning sed and want to use it to extract just the string that starts with zzz.

I though I could just grab everything between " psk=" and " }" but this does not seem to work:

```
sed 's_ psk=\(.*\) }_\1_' /tmp/myfile
```

I am also curious why it doesn't work. psk appears in the text twice but I though searching for " psk" would distinguish it from "#psk"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/.* psk=\([^ ]*\).*/\1/' file
```

Output:

```
zzzs93j03r093ur0fjfs39uj
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Add two `.*`: `sed 's_.* psk=\(.*\) .*}_\1_' /tmp/myfile`

Comment: Ah because I was only matching some of the text before and after and what I need to do was match between everything_before_substring( )everything_after_substring right?

Comment: you were trying to match a `' '` before the psk not a `'#'` as is present? Or I'm misreading..

Comment: @red888: yes, you want to replace **complete line** by part in round brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Your command are working just fine, It replaces everything from `psk=...$` with `zzzs...`, what you want to add is `.*` in the front:

```
% sed 's_.* psk=\(.*\) }_\1_'
zzzs93j03r093ur0fjfs39uj
```

You can change your regex a little to handle cases where `psk` is not at the end:

```
sed 's/.*[^#]psk=\([[:alnum:]]*\).*/\1/'
```